# Adding aria label to link

Tags: php, html, attributes

how to add aria-label, i used w3 validator and there was this warning: Possible misuse of aria-label. I added aria-label like this:

```
<i aria-label="Arrow previous link" class="ti-arrow-left">
```

How to fix this line of code:

```
 next_post_link('%link', '<i aria-label="Arrow previous link" class="ti-arrow-left"></i>');
```

Comment: Because the `<i>` tag denotes voice for an element the label would not be valid. Instead, surround the tag with a labeled span. `<span aria-label="Arrow previous link" class="ti-arrow-left"><i></i></span>`

Comment: We don’t know what `next_post_link` is, so your question is rather impossible to answer to begin with, if you actually want to output this attribute on the `a` element itself. Whether this label would have any benefit, depends on what your link contains to begin with - in terms of accessibility, ideally that should be a _text_ description, possibly hidden from non visually impaired users in favor of such an icon. Right now, your question contains way too little detail for a proper answer, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your functions.php file:

```
function posts_link_next_aria($format){
     $format = str_replace('href=', 'aria-label="Click for Next Promotion" href=', $format);
     return $format;
}
add_filter('next_post_link', 'posts_link_next_aria');

function posts_link_prev_aria($format) {
     $format = str_replace('href=', 'aria-label="Click for Previous Promotion" href=', $format);
     return $format;
}
add_filter('previous_post_link', 'posts_link_prev_aria');
```

Then go to the WAVE website to check: https://wave.webaim.org/